# Git script is running differently when I run it through subprocess.check_output?

Tags: python, git, bash

When I run this Bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /srv/http
unset GIT_DIR

git commit -am "design changes"
git push -u origin master
git checkout dev
git merge master
git commit -am "design changes"
git checkout master
```

through the command line, I get this output

```
[master 914422f] design changes
 1 file changed, 17 deletions(-)
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 334 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
To https://blah@bitbucket.org/blah/blah.git
   562207f..914422f  master -> master
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.
Switched to branch 'dev'
Updating 562207f..914422f
Fast-forward
 save-design | 17 -----------------
 1 file changed, 17 deletions(-)
On branch dev
nothing to commit, working directory clean
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
```

but when I run it through Python using

```
subprocess.check_output('./save-design', shell=True)
```

I get this output

```
M   save-design
Already up-to-date.
M   save-design
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: A bunch of git output will be suppressed because stdout is a pipe rather than a tty (try running your script as `./save-design | cat` to see this happen without involving python).  The `M  save-design` I'm not sure of off-hand: since you're using `git commit -a`, it seems it should just get committed.  Note that you can use a pty from Python to get git to act like it's interactive (because a pty *is* interactive).

Comment: I just ran ./save-design | cat and it actually showed me the exact same thing (the correct output).

Comment: Ah, my mistake here: in the git source, the thing that inhibits progress indication ("compressing", etc) is `progress = isatty(2)` (not `isatty(1)`) so you have to pipe stderr too—which `subprocess.check_output` does *not* do.  So now I'm back to "can't explain either one"...  One other thought comes to mind, does your Python code change directories somewhere so that `./save-design` is some other version of the script?  (Unlikely but not impossible.)

Comment: No, because I modified the script to print something out and the output adjusted accordingly. Also, why the downvote? :3

Comment: I didn't downvote, no idea who did.

Comment: I think stderr is also captured by `subprocess.check_output`, since it can display it if you pass `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know why it's happening, but I fixed it by running it by sshing to localhost:

```
subprocess.check_output('ssh localhost "/srv/http/save-design"', shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

could it be that you aren't setting the working directory for subprocess.check_output and so git is picking up whatever random working directory gets set?

```
subprocess.check_output('./save-design', cwd='/my/working/dir/', shell=True)
```